# Magento 2 : filter product collection

Tags: magento2, php

I would like to filter on a custom attribute all product collection. I tried to use the `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event but I can't filter collection as it's already loaded here.

The event `catalog_product_collection_load_before` does not exist. Is there any solution to do this ?

Here's the code I tried :

```
<event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
    <observer name="plugin" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductCollection" />
</event>
```

Observer.php

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute', ['lteq' => "xx"]);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Create plugin rather than using observer.

Comment: i am not sure.
.. I think, you need to call load() after addFieldToFilter(). 
let's try it.

Comment: @NaveedAsim I tried to use plugin but it does not work either.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngTuấn I tried to call load() but I'm getting an Illegal State error